# URL with query disables caching?

Tags: cache, query-string

Does having a query string attached to a URL cause browsers to never cache it? For instance,  my site does something like this:

`/radar-picture.png?v=sep2013`

And it would appear that FireFox never caches that picture; it is downloaded on every request.

I'd like FireFox to cache it, for as long as it wants to. I only want to force it to download when the `v=` parameter has changed.

Comment: I guess you could accomplish this, if you just change the filename itself instead of the query. So now the filename would be `radar-picture-sep2013.png` and when it changes at some point in the future it would be `radar-picture-jan2014.png`. You can configure the PNG's max-age to a year so unless the filename changes, the browser can load the cached picture for a long time.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a query-string key/value pair to a static resource (such as an image, CSS or JavaScript) [can cause caching issues](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/).

Specifically, since you mentioned *Firefox*, your issue could be related to a 'Cache collision', where:

> **The Firefox disk cache hash functions can generate collisions for URLs that differ only slightly, namely only on 8-character boundaries.** When resources hash to the same key, only one of the resources is persisted to disk cache; the remaining resources with the same key have to be re-fetched across browser restarts. Thus, if you are using fingerprinting or are otherwise programmatically generating file URLs, to maximize cache hit rate, avoid the Firefox hash collision issue by ensuring that your application generates URLs that differ on more than 8-character boundaries.

[Source: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching ]

Comment: What is "8-character boundary" and HOW can I avoid this collision? How should my URLs look like then?

Answer (score 2):

This answer on stackoverflow claims that some browsers react differently to hitting enter in the address bar vs clicking on a link when the url has a query string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/85386/1145388

When you are testing, make sure you are clicking on links rather than refreshing or hitting enter in the url bar.

Comment: I think that answer on stackoverflow may be outdated. When I put a query string on stylesheets `style.css?v=sep2013` and the 150KiB `background-image:url('bgimage.jpg?v=sep2013');`, navigating the site (via clicking links, or typing in address-bar) is very slow in FireFox.